# Hiding a winform & bringing it back from a DLL

Tags: c++, winforms, dll, name-decoration

In my DDL, I have the following function defined:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void hideme(HWND h) {
    //ShowWindow(h, SW_HIDE);
    SendMessage(h, WM_SHOWWINDOW, FALSE, 0);
}
```

As you can see, I've tried multiple things to get this working...

I have it declared in my winform as followed:

```
typedef void (*HideMe)(HWND);
```

In my System::Windows::Forms::Form Load event, I have the following code:

```
...
HINSTANCE hinst = LoadLibrary(_T("My.dll"));
if (hinst == NULL)
    System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("null hinst"); 
else
    hideme = (HideMe) GetProcAddress(hinst, "hideme");
...
```

In my System::Windows::Forms::Form Shown event, I have the following code:

```
...
hideme((HWND)this->Handle.ToPointer());
...
```

I think the problem must lie in the way I send over the HWND, but I've been searching all day, and can't find an alternative.

I've also tried setting this->Visible = false; but then I can't figure out how to trigger it back to visible from the DLL (abuse sendmessage?).

I'm not a C++ programmer, I normally only program in managed languages, so any help (and patience is appreciated.

Thanks,

Nick.

N.B.

One weird thing I can't explain is that I can't call ShowWindow from the WinForm itself. It will throw up this gem:

```
Error   2   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00001E) "extern "C" int __stdcall ShowWindow(struct HWND__ *,int)" (?ShowWindow@@$$J18YGHPAUHWND__@@H@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall CheckMSNCpp::frmMain::frmMain_Shown(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?frmMain_Shown@frmMain@CheckMSNCpp@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __stdcall ShowWindow(struct HWND__ *,int)" (?ShowWindow@@$$J18YGHPAUHWND__@@H@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall CheckMSNCpp::frmMain::frmMain_Shown(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?frmMain_Shown@frmMain@CheckMSNCpp@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
Error   4   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

[EDIT1]

Hans Passant said:

> The linker error message you got on
>   the ShowWindow() attempt is also a
>   strong hint why your current code is
>   not working. You forgot to add error
>   checking code, GetProcAddress() can
>   fail and will return a NULL pointer.
>   It will, the function isn't exported
>   by the "hideme" name. In a 32-bit
>   build, it will be exported as
>   "_hideme", note the underscore. Which
>   was added to indicate that the
>   function uses the __cdecl calling
>   convention. The linker error on
>   ShowWindow demonstrates C++ name
>   decoration, you forgot to #include
>   windows.h and made up your own,
>   incorrect, declaration for ShowWindow.
>
> This is not the right way to do it,
>   you should just set the Visible
>   property to false. Like you tried. Why
>   you cannot set it back to true is
>   quite unguessable.

What you said makes no sense to me at all for a few reasons.

1)

The imports for the winform:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
```

As you can tell, windows.h is in there.

2) the ShowWindor error is not in the DLL, there I can call it fine, it's in the WinForm code.

3) I never exported ShowWindow, just my own functions.

[/EDIT1]

[EDIT2]
Uwe Keim said:

> Why do you need an extra DLL that is
>   merely just a wrapper to another DLL
>   function?
>
> I would do it like in e.g. C# by using
>   PInvoke from your managed C++
>   application. The signature for
>   SendMessage would be (in C#):

The PInvoke stuff just doesn't make any sense, like commenters said.

As for the DLL, it needs to be a DLL because i require a global hook to respond to my hotkeys & WH_CBT. In this case, I want the program to start hidden & just show a setting screen when pressing a key combo.

Everything in the program works as expected, the hotkey works like a charm, the only thin I can't get right, is showing the application, triggered from the DLL.
[/EDIT2]

[EDIT3]
Example code at: http://www.nickkusters.com/CPP_PROBLEM_Demo-NOBIN.zip
[/EDIT3]

Comment: This is bizarre on many levels. No need for direct win32 to hide a form. No need for DLLs in any case, can use Pinvoke. From managed C++ you can call win api direct anyway. Finally you don't send that message, it is sent to you. Read the documentation again. To hide a window in win api call ShowWindow.

Comment: I'd love to do that, but Calling ShowWindow with this->Handle.ToPointer() doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like we can't help you. Good luck.

Comment: Demo source @ http://www.nickkusters.com/CPP_PROBLEM_Demo-NOBIN.zip

Answer (score 1):

The linker error message you got on the ShowWindow() attempt is also a strong hint why your current code is not working.  You forgot to add error checking code, GetProcAddress() can fail and will return a NULL pointer.  It will, the function isn't exported by the "hideme" name.  In a 32-bit build, it will be exported as "_hideme", note the underscore.  Which was added to indicate that the function uses the __cdecl calling convention.  The linker error on ShowWindow demonstrates C++ name decoration, you forgot to #include windows.h and made up your own, incorrect, declaration for ShowWindow.

This is not the right way to do it, you should just set the Visible property to false.  Like you tried.  Why you cannot set it back to true is quite unguessable.

Comment: Edited my post to add your comment & response to make it clear. Couldn't do formatting in comments.

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.  Post the source code on a file sharing service or paste bin.  There is no need for a DLL to implement hot keys, you can use RegisterHotKey.  Even a low-level keyboard hook would do, doesn't require a DLL either.  You'll find many hits when you type 'registerhotkey' in the Search box at the upper right of this page.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to change the design? You don't address the problem at all. Please just address the question asked.

Comment: That is certainly no obligation at SO.  It makes little sense to downvote an answer because you didn't like a comment.  Well, good luck with it.  Bye.

Comment: Well, your comment contained info that was just incorrect (as I've explained in the post), but thanks for trying.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need an extra DLL that is merely just a wrapper to another DLL function?

I would do it like in e.g. C# by [using PInvoke from your managed C++ application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/pinvoke.aspx). The signature for `SendMessage` would be (in C#):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd, 
    UInt32 Msg, 
    IntPtr wParam, 
    IntPtr lParam);
```

Comment: There is very little point in using pinvoke in a C++/CLI program.

Comment: Edited my post to add your comment & response to make it clear. Couldn't do formatting in comments.